# Kotlin recycler view , cannot get the complete array

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
class Category_recycler_view (var arrayList: ArrayList<Category_Spinner_model>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Category_recycler_view.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.category_spinner_item,parent,false)
        val spinner_modal : Category_Spinner_model?  = arrayList.get(1)
        val ico = v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.category_ico)
        val text = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.category_text)
        val dropdown_ico = v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.category_dropdowm)
        ico?.setImageResource(spinner_modal!!.getIco())
        text.text = spinner_modal!!.getTextt()
        dropdown_ico.setImageResource(spinner_modal.getDropico())

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

       val itemsView  = arrayList[position]

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder (Itemview : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(Itemview) {

    }

}
```

I need every element of the array to display, but i can give only one index at a time how to display every element of the array modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateViewHolder()` is only for creating a view holder that can be used by any list item. You need to populate it in `onBindViewHolder()`.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.category_spinner_item,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val spinner_modal = arrayList[position]
    val ico = holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.category_ico)
    val text = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.category_text)
    val dropdown_ico = holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.category_dropdowm)
    ico?.setImageResource(spinner_modal.getIco())
    text.text = spinner_modal.getTextt()
    dropdown_ico.setImageResource(spinner_modal.getDropico())

}
```

However, you should avoid using `findViewById` in `onBindViewHolder` because then it has to search for the views again every time the view holder is recycled. Instead, you should create properties in your ViewHolder class for this. So a better complete solution is:

```
class Category_recycler_view (var arrayList: ArrayList<Category_Spinner_model>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Category_recycler_view.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.category_spinner_item,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val spinner_modal = arrayList[position]
        holder.ico.setImageResource(spinner_modal.getIco())
        holder.text.text = spinner_modal.getTextt()
        holder.dropdown_ico.setImageResource(spinner_modal.getDropico())
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder (Itemview : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(Itemview) {
        val ico: ImageView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.category_ico)
        val text: TextView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.category_text)
        val dropdownIco: ImageView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.category_dropdowm)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose if you want to set text to the text view in recyclerView then you need to do like this , consider it as an example ~

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

   holder.textView.text =  arrayList[position].someTextVariable

}
```

here someTextvariable is the variable under the model class which is of String Type